# ParseQueryAdapter on GitHub?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

Now that the Parse Android SDK is Open Source I went on there to find ParseQueryAdapter but couldn't find it in the project. Can anyone find it out there? Or are they not supporting it anymore?

I would like to contribute to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ParseQueryAdapter was moved to the ParseUI Android project

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android